# How to export const with logic using import in Ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am building an ionic3 app and running into a problem with setting a proxy.  In Browser ionic will recognize the path of my proxyUrl like below.

**ionic.config.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true,
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://www.example.net/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I run into the issue where ionic will recognize the path `/api` in my code for example in a get call `this.http.get('/api')...` but will not recognize the path in emulator or on device.

So to fix that I tried doing the following, if I am in a browser (mobileweb) set path to `/api` otherwise set the URL I want to hit.

**my-config.ts**

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export const api = (Platform.is('mobileweb')) ? "/api" : "https://www.example.net/api";
```

This won't work though because I cannot access `Platform` directly here.

Throwing an error on the `is(...)` saying `[ts] Property 'is' does not exist on type 'typeof Platform'.`

Any way I can implement this differently to export the url I want to by checking the platform I am on?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following that returns false as I get errors in emulator because of wrong url:

**Returns false**

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

let platform = new Platform();

export const api = (Platform.is('mobileweb')) ? "/api" : "https://www.example.net/api";
```

To test in constructor it returns true.

**Returns true**

```
export class Test {

    constructor(platform: Platform){
      console.log('InBrowser', platform.is('mobileweb'));
    }
}
```

Comment: 'mobileweb'  ...  hmmm interesting. I see it documented here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/platform/platform.ts In browser on mobile app.. as opposed to mobile ??

Comment: @JGFMK so I flipped the logic around and tested for `platform.is('mobile') ? 'https://www.example.net/api' : '/api'` instead but it is still returning false in emulator.

Comment: @Sam5487 - I assume your trying this because of blasted CORS issues?  I never came across this part of how to do the proxies when I read the Ionic forum posts.. I managed to get past it with ionic serve with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi - but still have issues with ionicview the previewing app. (REST APIs)

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

**my-config.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalProvider {
    public api: any;
    constructor(platform: Platform){
       this.api = (platform.is('mobileweb')) ? "/api" :"https://www.example.net/api";
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
import { GlobalProvider } from '../../providers/my-config';
export class Test {

    constructor(globalProvider: GlobalProvider){ 
           console.log(globalProvider.api)
    }
}
```