# Ionic running platform check not working as what API described

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, browser, ionic2

I am working with the [ionic-angularjs](/questions/tagged/ionic-angularjs) framework that gives me following definitions for a platform:

- `android` - on a device running Android.
- `cordova` - on a device running Cordova.
- `core` - on a desktop device.
- `ios` - on a device running iOS.
- `ipad` - on an iPad device.
- `iphone` - on an iPhone device.
- `mobile` - on a mobile device.
- `mobileweb` - in a browser on a mobile device.
- `phablet` - on a phablet device.
- `tablet` - on a tablet device.
- `windows` - on a device running Windows.

I have this code written in typescript, but the if condition does not work when the application is run on mobile browsers. I would expect to receive `mobileweb` but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyPage {
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {

    if (this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
        // login page 
    }
    else{
        // Home page
    }
  }
}
```

However that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion on how I can fix the problem.

Comment: Do you want anything expect android or iOS app?

Comment: I saw someone else having similar problems the other day posting about proxies to address CORS. Have linked it, in case it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242974/how-to-export-const-with-logic-using-import-in-ionic3

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the platform is ready before executing the code.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   // Your condition here 
})
```

Comment: I placed the log to know the "mobileweb" platform check in mobile browser. Eventhough the result of the mobileweb is false.